# Validate data in html table and color the cells acordingly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html table like this one to automaticaly validate the data received from some soil pollutants analyses :

```
<table id="table1">
  <thead class="fixedHeader">
<tr><input type="submit" value=" Validate "/><input type="reset"value="réinitialiser" "></tr> 
</thead>
   <tbody id="form1" class="scrollContent">
<tr>
   <td>COT</td>
   <td><input type="text" class="cellData" name="celula1" id="celula1" value="" /</td>
   <td>mg/kg</td>
   <td id="soilMessage1" class="y_n" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>HCT C10-C40</td>
   <td><input type="text" class="cellData" name="celula2" id="celula2" value="" /></td>
   <td><p>mg/kg</p></td>
   <td id="soilMessage2" class="y_n"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and this goes on for 37 cells but i posted just two to give you an ideea. 
Now I am trying to color the background of the cells "soilMessageX" according to the results obtained from this little script :

```
window.onload=function() {
document.getElementById("form1").onsubmit=function() 
   {
    var celula1 = parseInt(this.celula1.value,10); 
    celula2 = parseInt(this.celula2.value,10);
       {
var text1 ;  
 if (celula1 <= 399)  text1 = "FNADE Classe 3"; 
  else if (celula1 >= 400 && celula1 <= 1800) text1 = "FNADE Classe 2";  
  else if (celula1 >= 1801) text1 = "FNADE Classe 1" ;
  else text1 = "SVP inserez des donnes";
   document.getElementById("soilMessage1").innerHTML=text1; 
var text2 ; 
 if (celula2 <= 499) text2 = "FNADE Classe 3";  
  else if (celula2 >= 500 && celula2 <= 2000) text2 == "FNADE Classe 2";  
  else if (celula2 >= 2001 && celula2 >= 10000) text2 == "FNADE Classe 1";
  else if (celula2 > 10000 ) text4 = "Concentration trop élevée";
  else text2 = "SVP inserez des donnes";
   document.getElementById("soilMessage2").innerHTML=text2;
return false  
    }
    }   
     } ;
```

and this also goes on for 37 cells. (if you could give me an idea on how to simplify this I would be also grateful but this is not the main thing ).

I tried to use this script to change the color of the answer cell :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#form1 td.y_n:contains('FNADE Classe 3')").css('background-color','#fcc');
 });
</script>
```

but whith no results.

Could somebody please enlighten me ?
Thank You

Comment: You are missing a `)` at the end of the `$(document).ready` function

Comment: Your script to set soilmessage will run on submit of the form - but the script to color the background of the cells runs before that, on document load.

Comment: sorry, my bad just a typo here, but it's not the issue @spokey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cycle through the y_n cells and act accordingly:

```
$('#table1 td.y_n').each(function () {
    // 'this' is the cell so you can do your checks and then
    $(this).css(...);
});
```

Comment: and then I have to verify each cell separately, or it works for the whole array like in my case?

Comment: you check each cell in the function I posted above. just before the $(this).css line. The cell is identified by 'this'. the .each function cycles all the td elements with y_n class.

Comment: OK, I will try that, but isn't there an option to have a global function whit just 3 variables ?

Comment: if it's there i'm not aware of, sorry. :) btw i often try to follow the KISS principle (Keep It Simple Stupid) which saves a lot of time when you'll need to change it later. :)